# White object under pomegranate tree leaf

Tags: pest-control, pomegranate

[image]

Anybody know what this is on my pomegranate tree leaf?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like whiteflies. There is a surprising amount of info on wikipedia about them: control by chemical & non-chemical means, as well as fascinating factoids about their biology
...   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitefly